# SSL error bad handshake while calling databrick job from airflow Dag

Tags: airflow, databricks

I am running a airflow container in which 
My airflow dags fails to connect to Databrick job with the error log below.

> failed with reason: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Mycompany-dev.cloud.databricks.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

more Information:
Initially to install docker or java it was giving same error in which i rewrite the pip install code as below, however i am not sure how to include it while connecting to a server from airflow UI.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Comment: Did you happen to check if `Mycompany-dev.cloud.databricks.com` certificate is valid, manually?

Comment: could you please suggest how can i check if my certificate is valid.

Comment: `openssl`: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001177774-How-to-check-SSL-certificate-for-validity-

Comment: @devD did this resolve?